# Presto service for Worker/Coordinator is not starting

Tags: hive, ambari, presto

We've patch ambari to work with presto for ubuntu distribution, but after installation when service is invoked to get started, following error is coming in worker/coordinator node.

```
Show the stack trace when generating an error response
2017-04-24T13:00:24.280+0530    INFO    main    Bootstrap   http-server.threads.max-idle-time                                     1.00m                             1.00m
2017-04-24T13:00:24.280+0530    INFO    main    Bootstrap   http-server.auth.users-file                                           null                              null
2017-04-24T13:00:24.280+0530    INFO    main    Bootstrap   jmx.rmiregistry.port                                                  null                              null
2017-04-24T13:00:24.280+0530    INFO    main    Bootstrap   jmx.rmiserver.port                                                    null                              null
2017-04-24T13:00:24.280+0530    INFO    main    Bootstrap   node.binary-spec                                                      null                              null
2017-04-24T13:00:24.281+0530    INFO    main    Bootstrap   node.config-spec                                                      null                              null
2017-04-24T13:00:24.281+0530    INFO    main    Bootstrap   node.environment                                                      null                              production
2017-04-24T13:00:24.281+0530    INFO    main    Bootstrap   node.internal-address-source                                          IP                                IP
2017-04-24T13:00:24.281+0530    INFO    main    Bootstrap   node.location                                                         null                              null
2017-04-24T13:00:24.281+0530    INFO    main    Bootstrap   node.bind-ip                                                          null                              null
2017-04-24T13:00:24.281+0530    INFO    main    Bootstrap   node.external-address                                                 null                              null
2017-04-24T13:00:24.281+0530    INFO    main    Bootstrap   node.id                                                               null                              f85737c2-aaa9-44c7-ac12-004716129809
2017-04-24T13:00:24.281+0530    INFO    main    Bootstrap   node.internal-address                                                 null                              null
2017-04-24T13:00:24.281+0530    INFO    main    Bootstrap   node.pool                                                             general                           general
2017-04-24T13:00:24.281+0530    INFO    main    Bootstrap   
2017-04-24T13:00:25.086+0530    ERROR   main    com.facebook.presto.server.PrestoServer Unable to create injector, see the following errors:

1) Event class [class io.airlift.http.server.HttpRequestEvent] EventField method [public java.time.Instant io.airlift.http.server.HttpRequestEvent.getTimeStamp()] return type [class java.time.Instant] is not supported
  at io.airlift.http.server.HttpServerModule.configure(HttpServerModule.java:76)

1 error
com.google.inject.CreationException: Unable to create injector, see the following errors:

1) Event class [class io.airlift.http.server.HttpRequestEvent] EventField method [public java.time.Instant io.airlift.http.server.HttpRequestEvent.getTimeStamp()] return type [class java.time.Instant] is not supported
  at io.airlift.http.server.HttpServerModule.configure(HttpServerModule.java:76)

1 error
    at com.google.inject.internal.Errors.throwCreationExceptionIfErrorsExist(Errors.java:466)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InternalInjectorCreator.initializeStatically(InternalInjectorCreator.java:155)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InternalInjectorCreator.build(InternalInjectorCreator.java:107)
    at com.google.inject.Guice.createInjector(Guice.java:96)
    at io.airlift.bootstrap.Bootstrap.initialize(Bootstrap.java:242)
    at com.facebook.presto.server.PrestoServer.run(PrestoServer.java:116)
    at com.facebook.presto.server.PrestoServer.main(PrestoServer.java:67)
```

Any clue, what's misconfigured in the settings, following are config files.

**config.properties**

```
query.max-memory=50GB
node-scheduler.include-coordinator=false
query.max-memory-per-node=1GB
http-server.http.port=8285
discovery.uri=http://ambari-slave1.stg-dp-ranger.stg.XXX.net:8285
coordinator=true
discovery-server.enabled=true
```

Answer (score 0):

As the error states, `java.time.Instant` is missing. This class was introduced by Java 8, which [Presto requires](https://prestodb.io/overview.html). So I assume that your problem is due to the fact that you have a lower Java version than 8 installed.

Comment: It's already Java 8
java version "1.8.0_101"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_101-b13)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.101-b13, mixed mode)